# how get domain value form post to controller

Tags: grails

this is the form for send data value

[image]

And this is the controller that value the post
[image]

Comment: Please paste your actual code instead of screenshots.

Comment: <g:each in="${surveyHeaderInstance?.surveyDetails.sort{it.sequence}}" status="i" var="surveyDetail">
       <ul class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}" >       
        
           <g:hiddenField name="${surveyHeaderInstance?.id}"  />

        <li>${fieldValue(bean: surveyDetail, field: "question")}</li>

<g:if test='${surveyDetail?.datatype == 'Numeric'}' >

                                   <input type="number" name="${surveyDetail?.question}">
                                 //   i want get this value question on controller
    </g:if>

Comment: def save(OrderSurvey orderSurveyInstance) {
        if (orderSurveyInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }


    // println  "params"+params.surveyHeaderInstance?.surveyDetails?.question
    // println  "params"+params.question
    println  params
and this is on cotroller

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding your question is not very clear to me, about this I would recommend trying to abstract the essential of your question and eliminate the noise. Probably your question could be: How could I get the value of a parameter whose name is assigned dynamically? If this is the case the answer could be that instead of passing the question you pass the id of the question and in the controller get the question through the id

Comment: sorry i am a new user, i am adjusting to this community
I mean how to get specific value
such as question
but when i use params.question the value is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input field is named `${surveyDetail.question}` which is the value of the question attribute.  It should be named `question` which you can then access via `params.question`.

Input field:

```
<input type="text" name="question" value="${surveyDetail.question}" />
```

In controller:

```
def value = params.question
```